# Multilingual windows phone application

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I'm looking for a solution how to use resx files and create a multilingual application. On the Internet, I can't find any guide on how to do it exactly. I would like to be able to add the xaml file, for example:

```
<TextBlock Text="Multilingual text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

> Localizing resources in Windows Phone 8 requires the developer to
>   create multiple `resource` files. Creating multiple resource files for
>   different languages respectively and putting all the corresponding
>   translations of strings you want to make multilingual in separate
>   files.

Simply create resource file like `AppResources.es.resx` if you wan't your all strings to be specific for Espanol (`AppResources.resx` contains all the default resources you wan't to provide as your application's default language).